# Smoke wont update when moving the source or resizing the domain?

Tags: smoke-simulation, error

I tried making a normal smoke simulation with the usual domain and the generator, the smoke starts the moment i click the quick smoke but stays in the first frame, when i resize the domain, the smoke sizes up as well, and doesnt update when moving the generator, no matter what i do.
anyone know how to fix this?

The Box shown in the render is another cube, i didnt edit the domain in any way besides resizing

Im using Blender 2.83, downloaded from steam

Link to render and blender file: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13qhZd3OP0e5x91m5dTPqKk7N3aTcjpfI?usp=sharing

[image: quick smoke when just made]

[image: domain resized]

Comment: Free bake and rebake it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a known bug with current Blender versions when using a Replay Cache (in the Domain settings, the Cache -> Type -> Replay setting).  See issues [77170](https://developer.blender.org/T77170) and [76095](https://developer.blender.org/T76095).

As a quick fix, you can go into the domain settings, and change just about anything (e.g., temporarily change the resolution divisions).  That'll invalidate and regenerate the cache, and your smoke should start generating from the new cube position.

You could also consider switching the cache from Replay to Modular, which gives you Bake and Free buttons to allow more direct control over the cache.

Comment: For info, you don’t actually need to *change* the resolution setting to force a refresh - just click in the field and press Enter to accept it as it is and that is enough to invalidate the cache.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue where I could not move my smoke around by navigating to the Physics settings of the Smoke Domain, select Fluid, scroll down to Cache, and delete the existing filepath from the textbox. I do not know what the long-term impacts will be, but this fixed my immediate problem.